# Export QWidget as a QSystemTrayIcon

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, system-tray, window-managers

I am trying to put "Application Menu" `org.kde.plasma.kicker` at my tiling window manager which does implement `XEmbed` protocol of the X11, without starting the KDE system tray. For that, I can call the "Application Menu" plasmoid/applet from within command line by `plasmawindowed org.kde.plasma.kicker`, but it is not registered as a system tray object.

I found the API to create QSystemTrayIcon [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html), and an example [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-systray-example.html), but they all involve implementing the widget from scratch using C++ then compiling it. Is there any other way to make this widget window as a TrayIcon object?

This is the `org.kde.plasma.kicker` widget/applet/plasmoid started from the command line as a single window:
[image]

This is how a system tray icon (fcitx) is placed in my window manager (i3):
[image]

I would like to make this QWidget as a QSystemTrayIcon object so that it could be placed along with the fcitx icon in the tray, instead of a random place as a floating window:
[image]

Some discussion on the i3wm dev page:
https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/2119#event-493172020